# Place a text content in the middle of a container

Tags: elm

I am using collage, so that the elements will be placed in the  middle of the box.

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)
import Graphics.Collage exposing (collage)

textBox =
  show "hello world"

main =
  collage 1000 1000 [textBox]
```

But there is a typemismatch error at the last line as,

```
Graphics.Element.Element
Graphics.Collage.Form
```

Since, `show` function returns `Element` whereas `collage` accepts only `Form`. What other function can i use, to position the text content in the middle of the `collage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert an Element to a Form with Graphics.Collage.toForm

```
toForm : Element -> Form
```

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Graphics-Collage#toForm

Your program simply becomes

```
main = collage 1000 1000 [toForm textBox]
```

Answer (score 4):

grumpyjames' answer is right about converting `Element` to `Form` to put them on a collage. I just want to point out that you don't *need* to use a collage to put an `Element` in the center. The `Graphics.Element` package has a [container](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Graphics-Element#container) function that will serve a similar purpose to collage, but with `Element` instead of `Form`. So you could also do:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)

main =
  container 1000 1000 middle (show "Hello, World!")
```

Comment: collage vs contaiiner... this was in fact a question on the back of my mind... i am so glad, you answered it.. thanks robert